# Gettext does not flag python format strings with "python-format" unlike old style python strings with format specifiers

Tags: python, internationalization, gettext, format-string

It seems that gettext is not able to recognise Python format strings with replacement fields properly and hence does not flag them as "python-format". E.g.

```
ugettext("This is a sample format string with a {kwarg}").format(kwarg='key word argument')
```

However, gettext identifies Python strings with format specifiers properly and flags such source strings with "python-format", e.g.,

```
ugettext("This is a sample string with a %(format_spec).") % {'format_spec': 'format specifier'}
```

I have tried using `xgettext` and Django's `manage.py makemessages` tools to generate PO files for Python format strings, but didn't see the Python format strings being flagged as "python-format".

Also, http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/Python.html does not specify anything about the new Python format strings.

Please help me find a work around for this issue.

Comment: Not sure how it'll fare with string formats, but have you looked at [Babel](http://babel.edgewall.org/) at all? It's certainly better than xgettext and friends for string extraction, and it's pluggable.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for replying. I tried Babel out. It's also not able to detect a Python format string as a python string :\

Comment: Sorry to hear that; it'll require some custom development then to add such a parser to Babel.

Comment: Perhaps you could try the C# parser? Not sure whether that handles named arguments though.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you are being hit by this  [bug](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=668226): the `gettext` tools support only the old Python string format for substitutions. So you should use old string format. Or you can use a different tool for doing your translations.

Comment: Out of date after the changes mentioned by Tobias above.

Answer (score 0):

This flag `python-format` refers to the classic `__mod__` replacement method which uses the `%` operator.  The newer *format* mini-language is something completely different and of course can't share the same format flag.

For someone who freshly jumps in and was told to use `.format` because it is new and flexible this might be confusing; but the flag name must contain `-format` for consistency reasons and is not at all related to the name of the used Python mechanism.

The "classic" style has the advantage of being faster. Something like

```
kwarg = 'keyword argument'
ugettext('This is a sample format string with a %(kwarg)s') % locals()
```

should be recognized, and flagged as `python-format`.

Something like

```
ugettext('This is a sample format string with a %s') % (kwarg,)
```

would be flagged as `c-format`.

(You need to take care for the translation of "keyword argument" yourself elsewhere, of course.)

**Update:** Apparently, the [format flag for the `.format()` syntax is `python-brace-format`](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gettext/2012-12/msg00031.html).

Comment: How to take care of this kind of translations elsewhere?

Comment: @Jay: I don't understand your question: What do you mean by "elsewhere"? However, the thing to do would probably be: create a question ...